# ReactJS OnChange doesn't seem to be working on IOS Safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, mobile, safari

I'm using ReactJS and I've created some inputs which is then calculated and displayed in an accordion. Everything displays fine on Chrome Desktop and Mobile and Safari on Desktop, but the only device it doesn't work on is Safari on Mobile. Not sure why...

*Input Snippet:*

```
<td className="tables">
  <div style={{ position: 'relative' }} ref={eventRefs2.current[index]}>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Single"
        name={"table_type_" + index}
        value="single"
        onChange={handleButton}
        data-index={index}
      />
      Single table
    </label>
  </div>
</td>
```

*Accordion Snippet:*

```
<Accordion className="mobileSavings" allowZeroExpanded style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
  <AccordionItem key={"@#7TG"}>
    <AccordionItemHeading>
      <AccordionItemButton className="mobileSavingsButton">
        <span style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} className="savings-arrow">
          view savings
        </span>
      </AccordionItemButton>
    </AccordionItemHeading>
    <AccordionItemPanel className="mobileSavingsPanel">
      <h4 style={{ color: "#FAE271" }}>currency</h4>
      <select
        name="currency"
        id="currency"
        className="sidebar__dropdown roundArrow"
        defaultValue={priceType}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <option value="usd">US Dollars</option>
        <option value="gbp">British Pound</option>
        <option value="eur">Euros</option>
      </select>

      <p>
        you save:{" "}
        {(() => {
          if (priceType === "gbp") {
            return (
              <span style={{ color: "#FAE271" }}>
                £{result.yousave}
              </span>
            );
          } else if (priceType === "usd") {
            return (
              <span style={{ color: "#FAE271" }}>
                ${result.yousave}
              </span>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <span style={{ color: "#FAE271" }}>
                €{result.yousave}
              </span>
            );
          }
        })()}
      </p>
    </AccordionItemPanel>
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

Is there something that isn't supported on iOS?

I've tried to use multiple devices and the only device it doesn't work on is Safari iOS.